# multiply rows by the numerical value of an entry

Tags: r, vector, multiplication

In R i have a matrix that has several categorical values to it. Indexed size 2sqm, 4 sqm, 6sqm, number of units from 1-3, number of persons from 1-4 and then a column that has a summarized count from all the occurrences.

ex:

```
Size;Units;Pers;Count
4;3;4;3 # three time this row
2;1;1;2 # two times this row
6;2;2;1 # one times this row
```

How can i make the last column/vector multyply the rows so that is prints out:

```
Size;Units;Pers;Count
4;3;4;1
4;3;4;1
4;3;4;1
2;1;1;1
2;1;1;1
6;2;2;1
```

Either in spreadsheet or in R. 
This is a assignment for school and i just cannot find the way to make the last vector (which i use as a constant to multiply the first 3 columns and yet still keep one in the last column entry.

Comment: Well, thanks to @SamFirke, you should learn that even if you can't figure it out by yourself, you should at least be able to research around because most often the answer is out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can replicate the sequence of rows by the 'Count' column and `transform` to create the 'Count' column of 1.

```
transform(df1[rep(1:nrow(df1), df1$Count),-4], Count=1)
```

This can be also done with wrapper function `expandRows` from `library(splitstackshape)`

```
library(splitstackshape)
transform(expandRows(df1, 'Count'), Count=1)
```